# select data that must exist on two tables and ignoring that exist in one table only

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have two tables students table and subjects, student_id is the foreign key in subject table, i want to pick students whose student_id  appeared on subject table, and i want to return only single row, your help please.

early i select students who appeared on students table and do not appear on subject and here in code

```
  $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('students AS t')
        ->where('t.student_id NOT IN (select student_id from subjects)',NULL,FALSE);


$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

i think the answer will be opposite of what i did early.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the example is the opposite

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('students AS t')
    ->where('t.student_id IN (select student_id from subjects)');


$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

Just remove the word "NOT", and that should work.

EDIT::
Removed ',NULL,FALSE' from the end of the query, since they are not required. Including these would pull results where the field was NULL or FALSE. Which is not the intended outcome.

Comment: what about ,NULL, FALSE

Comment: Good point, you don't need it there. Didn't see it. Edited answer.